# Interactive Section header of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have `UITableView` in which I have added a `UIButton`. The problem is it is only showing in on the top of the header. How can I add the button in all of the section headers so that I can make the section interactive?

Here is the code for adding a button on Section Header of `UITableView`

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 200/255, blue: 20/255, alpha: 1.0) // Just some random color
    header.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let btn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(header.frame.width - 62, 0, 50, 50)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    btn.setTitle("Direction", forState: .Normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    header.contentView.addSubview(btn)      
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to add interactive button on every section?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use this delegate

```
optional public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

to customize the headerview section of tableview

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
   let header: = UIView()
   let btn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(header.frame.width - 62, 0, 50, 50)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    btn.setTitle("Direction", forState: .Normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)

    header.addSubview(btn)
    return header

}
```

Comment: Is there any possibility of expanding sections. When I tried to add this i am not able to see section title.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Simply this delegate Method Of Tableview :

```
optional public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```